# Updating a row in Laravel 5.7 doesn't work, how do I fix it?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to update a row in mysql table. However, when I click the **register button**, it doesn't do anything. I'm using Laravel.

Here's my `update` function:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $idpawn = $request['idprestamo'];
    $paynumber = $request['numeropago'];
    $payqty = $request['payqty'];
    $statuspawns = statuspawns::find($idpawn,$paynumber);
    $updateqty = $statuspawns->totalpayment - $payqty;

    if($updateqty  == "0"){
        $status = "Pay";
    }
    else{
        $status = "Partial Payment";
    }

    $statuspawns->total = $updateqty;
    $statuspawns->status = $status;
    $statuspawns->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Also, can you post your code which has the **register** button.

Comment: You should also explain how your `update` function is connected with the DB table that you are trying to update. I'm not a Laravel user, but it's totally unclear to me, so may be worth clarifying for others as well. Is `statuspawns` a part of ORM of the table? You should probably include the code that shows that, into your question.

Comment: Do you have the fields to be updated added in the `$fillable` array in your statuspawns model? `$fillable = ['status', 'total'];` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you need square brackets instead of parenthesis since it's an array. `$request['idprestamo']`
`$request['numeropago']`
`$request['payqty']`

I'd like to also add that you can do it this way also with a magic method...

`$request->numeropago`

Comment: I change, but the problem continue

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the `Request` this way `$request->input_name` not this way `$request('input_name')` because it is a [Laravel Data Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections)

In the end of the day, your function will look like this:

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $idpawn = $request->idprestamo;
        $paynumber = $request->numeropago;
        $payqty = $request->payqty;
        $statuspawns = statuspawns::find($idpawn,$paynumber);
        $updateqty = $statuspawns->totalpayment - $payqty;

        if($updateqty  == "0"){
            $status = "Pay";
        }
        else{
            $status = "Partial Payment";
        }

        $statuspawns->total = $updateqty;
        $statuspawns->status = $status;
        $statuspawns->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

## UPDATE

In Laravel 5.7 you have to use the `update()` method instead of the `save()` method to update a row.

Answer (score 0):

You are not retrieving the record correctly. you have to pass only id to  **find()**. As you have passed two parameters.

change this statement to..

```
$statuspawns = statuspawns::find($idpawn,$paynumber);
```

To

```
$statuspawns = statuspawns::find($idpawn);
```

Now you can update the columns which you want to update.

Comment: you have to pass only primary key for single record or array of primary keys for multiple records to find() function.